# Failed to Ingest data to mooncake, Failed to create ResourceManager from URI - invalid uri

Tags: node.js, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

folks

I was trying to use the node package 'azure-kusto-ingest' to ingest data to a cluster in mooncake -- the sovereign cloud of China. but failed and given error below:

```
Error: Failed to create ResourceManager from URI - invalid uri (https://gwqkstrldazurecxpcrecn01.queue.core.chinacloudapi.cn/aggregatorinput-secured?sv=XXXXXXX)
```

been stuck here for while and don't have any clue, any idea is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify azure-kusto-ingest package version

Comment: "azure-kusto-ingest": "^3.3.2",

Comment: Thank you for reporting, we have found that it is a bug, and we will release version 3.4.0 shortly with the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.4.0 was just publish -https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-kusto-ingest

Let us know if the problem persists.